# How to return data from a separate process (like queue) without closing it so you can send it more data later

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

The reason I am trying to do this is because Windows is terribly slow at opening and closing processes all the time. Its terribly inefficient which is the anti-purpose of multiprocessing. If one could start say 10 processes that do a specific operation on some data that can return the data (with queue or something) without closing it so you can send it more data to operate on and return. Basically a hive of processes holding functions that are always open ready to process and return data without death on the return so you don't have to keep opening new ones. I guess I could just run Linux Debian Crunchbang but I want to make it Windows efficient as well.

```
import multiprocessing

def operator_dies(data, q):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data % i == 0:
            return q.put(0) # Function and process die here
    return q.put(1) # And here


def operator_lives(data, q):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data % i == 0:
            q.put(0) # I want it to stay open, but send data back with q.put()
    q.put(1) # Same


def initialize(data):
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = [multiprocessing.Process(target=operator_dies, args=data, q]
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    # Multiprocessing.Process will open more processes.
    # Is there another multiprocessing function that can send new data as 
    # arguments in the function of an already open process ID and reset its loop?
    # I cannot simply do: q.put().processid from here to refresh 
    # a variable for arguments in an open process can I?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize(data)
```

Comment: Wait..I think I found the answer. Go here:
https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#multiprocessing-queues

Comment: Sorry, I guess I shouldn't have wasted anyone's time but I guess this thread might help others find help in the future.

Comment: I don't know why the official documentation website lacks examples like on https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#multiprocessing-queues